# TYPO3 Special menu content element

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

I am working on TYPO3 6.2 and In a page I have added the content element "Special menu" with the the option Site map with selected page. I was able to render this with out any issues.For almost all pages I have added navigation title and obviously in the site map also this navigation title will be displayed.My requirement is that I want to show title instead of nav_title.Tried the below code and doesn't seems to work . Can any one help me with this?

```
tt_content.menu.20.2.1 {
NO {
    stdWrap.cObject = COA
    stdWrap.cObject {
    10 = TEXT
    10.field = subtitle
  }
  ATagTitle.field = subtitle
 }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Insert the following lines to the setup field of an ext-template at the page where you want to display the plugin "Special menu" with option "Site map" and wont to change link title to subtitle.

```
tt_content.menu.20.2 >
tt_content.menu.20.2 = HMENU
tt_content.menu.20.2.1 = TMENU
tt_content.menu.20.2.1 {
expAll = 1
wrap = <ul>|</ul>
  NO{
    wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
    stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
    stdWrap.field = subtitle//title # add title of link subtitle or if empty title
    ATagTitle.field = nav_title//title #title add tag title what you need
  }
}
tt_content.menu.20.2.2 < tt_content.menu.20.2.1
tt_content.menu.20.2.3 < tt_content.menu.20.2.1
tt_content.menu.20.2.4 < tt_content.menu.20.2.1
```

Example http://www.typozone.com/index.php?id=96